# Sending struct through queue

Tags: c, embedded, freertos

Can someone help me figure out why this struct isn't being properly received over a queue in FreeRTOS I've looked through almost every post on this topic and can't get it to work.

```
typedef struct {
int id;
char* name;
} message;

void Start_Init(void *argument)
{
  /* init code for USB_DEVICE */
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  message mes;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
    Screen HOME;
    mes.id=77;
    mes.name = "test";
    SCREEN_INIT(&HOME,7,6,(char**)HOME_SCREEN,HOME_DATLOC,HOME_SEL);
    vTaskSuspend(ReadCardHandle);
    vTaskSuspend(WriteCardHandle);
    vTaskSuspend(HomeHandle);
    MFRC_INIT();
    MFRC_ANTOFF();
    OLED_INIT();
    OLED_Print(TC);
    while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1)!=0);
    xQueueSend(DisplayDataHandle,&mes,portMAX_DELAY); //sending test message here
    osDelay(100);
    vTaskSuspend(NULL);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 5 */

  void StartUpdateDisplay(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartUpdateDisplay */
    message rec;
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
    xQueueReceive(DisplayDataHandle, &rec, portMAX_DELAY); //Receive from queue here
    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END StartUpdateDisplay */
}
}
```

In debugging this is the state of `rec`:

[image]

Comment: You can't usefully send a pointer over the wire — yet that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: You don't show the `xQueueSend()` function, so I'm having to guess, but if you do the equivalent of `write(fd, mes, sizeof(*mes))`, you write the pointer and not the string to the receiver code.  If your structure was `typedef struct { int id; char message[MAX_MSG_LEN]; } message;`, then you'd be able to write the structure to the receiver without the same problem.

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense. I made that change and it seems to work now but I have to initialise the rec.id attritube to 0 in order to receive the correct 77 value. Why is this?

Comment: Please consider writing an answer post with the solution to the question you asked and then create another question post to ask the new question.

Comment: Do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).